# Ionic Package ios Error. aps-environment entitlement

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic's package service to build my ios app. When I build it I m getting the error

```
Provisioning profile "<PROVISIONING_PROFILE>" doesn't include the aps-environment entitlement. 
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'
```

I am not using push notifications and every issue online like this involved push notifications. I am Using Ionic Deeplink Plugin which could be causing the issue as it is the only thing in my app.Entitlements file. I have reinstalled it though and nothing was fixed.

I do have it set in my app provisioning profile and I have tried regenerating all my certificates and provisioning profiles.

Also my app was packaging fine about a week ago, then I added my project to GitHub last week and I haven't tried it until yesterday and it is not working. I don't feel like GitHub could be causing the issue. But I just wanted to put that out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It had something to do with uninstalling android as a platform. When I removed the android platform it stopped working and began to throw this error, but when I re-added android it began to work again. Strange...